# Selenium Webdriver NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am using Selenium webdriver with Python to print the contents an element but if it does not exist on the page it breaks my code and returns an exception error.

```
print (driver.find_element_by_id("TotalCost").text)
```

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element 
{"method":"id","selector":"TotalCost"}
```

What can i do to fix this error?

Comment: You can catch (`except NoSuchElementException as ex:`) this exception.

Comment: Where do i put that after the print statement? (except NoSuchElementException as ex:)

Comment: Read about [exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch the exception in a [`try...except`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) block:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    print(driver.find_element_by_id("TotalCost").text)
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Element not found")    # or whatever you want to print, or nothing
```

Could also do it this way for clarity:

```
try:
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id("TotalCost")
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
else:
    print(elem.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for making it clear i wasnt aware i needed 'import NoSuchElementException'. Which is why it wasnt working before!

Comment: Glad it worked out. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/193893)